# Bootstrap Column Not Aligning On The Right Side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a html page using Bootstrap containing rows.
I'm trying to split one row in three pieces but the third one is not getting aligned properly.

My Html Code:

```
  <!-- Row Containing 3 Columns -->
<div class="row">



    <div class="col-md-4" id="messagesBox" style="margin-left: 10px;">

        <h2>List Entries</h2>

        <!--
        <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <h3 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h3>
                    <small>3 days ago</small>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
                <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        -->
    </div>

    <!-- Gauge In Center Of Screen -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="gauge" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Section should be on the right side of the screen -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: orangered">
        <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I marked all columns by adding the class `col-md-4` the element with the id `messageBox` is getting aligned on the left side the `gauge` is centered, but the last column is not getting displayed on the right side.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your styles?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi his problem is reproducible with the code provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not aligning to the right, because the normal grid behavior is being overridden with the inline styles for `width` and `margin-left`..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="messagesBox">

            <h2>List Entries</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="gauge" style="height: 400px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Section should be on the right side of the screen -->
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: orangered">
            <div>Some content</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It works fine when you remove these styles:
http://www.codeply.com/go/mRedj994PD

Answer (score 2):

Remove margin in the left most column.

Answer (score 1):

Never add margin on the columns div, if you want to give the margin then add another div and add on it but not on column div. here is you updated code

HTML

```
<div class="row">



    <div class="col-md-4" id="messagesBox" >

        <h2>List Entries</h2>

        <!--
        <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <h3 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h3>
                    <small>3 days ago</small>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
                <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        -->
    </div>

    <!-- Gauge In Center Of Screen -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="gauge" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Section should be on the right side of the screen -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: orangered">
        <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `pull-right`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 pull-right" style="background-color: orangered">
        <div>Some content</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```